# navigation title on previous screen disappear when back button pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, title, back-button, navigationbar

i have a problem with navigation bar title. i have 2 screen, when i click back button on screen 2 it will back to screen 1 but the title of screen 1 is disappear. Here is my snippet code

screen1 .m

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.title = @"title 1";
....
```

screen 2 .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.title = self.stringTitle;

    // change the back button and add an event handler
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    //set custom image to button if needed
    UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(-12, 2, backButtonImage.size.width, backButtonImage.size.height);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, backButtonImage.size.width-15, backButtonImage.size.height)];
    [backButtonView addSubview:button];

    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButtonView];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
....
}

- (void) backAction
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

i've tried several tricks to make title of screen 1 appears with the following tricks:

1. set title on `viewwillappear` method

   ```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{self.title = @"tes";}
   ```
2. set title on `viewdidappear` method

   ```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"YourTitle";
     self.title = @"tes";
     }
   ```

but the title is still disappears. please help

---

here is the way how i moving to next screen

```
- (IBAction)btGenerateTokenAction:(id)sender {
    SofttokenResultController *controller = [[SofttokenResultController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SofttokenResultController" bundle:nil];

    controller.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"Kembali";
    [ViewLoadingUtil animateToNextView:controller from:self :@""];
}

+ (void) animateToNextView:(UIViewController *)controller from:(UIViewController *)fromController :(NSString *)navTitle{

    NSLog(@"animateToNextView called");

    [fromController.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: How are you moving from screen1 to screen2?

Comment: try `self.navigationItem.title`.

Comment: first time is it visible(before going to VC2). And y u add back button.if u using navigationBar ,default back Button will be der

Comment: did you add any view to your navigation controller title view

Comment: @Suhail yes it is visible before moving to screen2

Comment: @ChinttuRoxeNRamani i've tried adding self.navigationItem.title on viewDidLoad method but still disappear

Comment: @Fogmeister i'm moving to next screen using this method

edit: adding method how i move to next screen on first thread

Comment: remove this line `self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};` and see if the it works correctly (May not be desirable, but yet check it ou).

Comment: Test without hiding the back button and comment all codes related to back button and title view attributes.

Answer (score 15):

This solved my problem:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
        self.navigationItem.title="Title text"
}
```

Comment: From the docs... `If you override this method, you must call super in your implementation.`

Comment: This didnt solve my problem. I had to add the Dispatch Queue. So if anybody needs add the code   DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Your screen title"
    }

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was the `backItem?.title` that was the problem. In both my view controller and within a custom subclass of `UINavigationController` I was setting it to an empty string:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    ...
    navigationController.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""
}
```

My guess would be that when using `popViewController(animated:)` the title is taken from `backItem?.title` and set into the main title attribute.

Comment: This is old, but the bug persists because I just had to face it to...

Answer (score 1):

In `viewWillAppear` implement this:

```
self.navigationItem.title="Title text";
```

Answer (score 0):

it usually happen when you set backItem?.title = "" because the title of the back controller is taken from this property
I face this issue from months and solved it just by commenting this line

Answer (score -1):

`Objective c` solution:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Title text";
}
```

Comment: From the docs... `If you override this method, you must call super in your implementation.`

Comment: @Fogmeister Done :)

Comment: @raed should be `[super viewWillAppear: animated];`

Answer (score -1):

Working for me solution. You can try this one:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
    self.navigationItem.title = "Title"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I come from the Swift world. However I tried many solutions. These were caused by the animation. If you change the Bool to false, it will solve your problem. Finally you can put your code in the viewWillAppear function.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if animated {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: From the docs... `If you override this method, you must call super in your implementation.`