# iOS Custom Navigation bar back button title disappears on tapping

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

Hello StackOverflow community,

I have a rather curious case of a customized back button on my navigation controller's navigation bar disappearing on interaction.

Some additional information is that my code is not using Storyboard and I use UIKit - everything including the UI has been build programatically.

**This is my set up:**

- I start with creating a custom UINavigationController subclass to abstract away all of my navigation controller related customizations
- Within this subclass, I have this method that get's called to customized the appearance of my back button

```
private func customizeBackButton() {
    let backImage = UIImage(named: "BackButton")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
    navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
    
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
      NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.panoStoryYellow,
      NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Montserrat-SemiBold", size: 15)!
    ], for: .normal)
}
```

- The above customization, gives the following result which is what I desire with Gallery being the title of my previous screen

[image: UINavigationController custom back button]

- When I tap towards the left most edge of the back button where the arrow is, the button works normally. However, if I tap on the label section of the back button, where the Gallery text is, the text disappears and keeps the user on the same screen.

[image: UINavigationController UINavigationBarButton back button disappears]

When I tap on the back arrow after the label disappears, it works and takes me back to the previous screen, however, why would this disappearance occur ?

**What have I tried**
I have tried many suggestions on stack overflow such as:

- making sure no line in my code hides the back button explicitly
- Checking that previous screen's title to an empty string at any point

I can confirm that these are not the issue as I have a valid title and never hide the back button.

Here are some resources I have checked before deciding that none of them work for my case and I asked the question on here:

[UINavigationController Back Button not visible, but works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485671/uinavigationcontroller-back-button-not-visible-but-works)

[UINavigationController's back button disappears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919832/uinavigationcontrollers-back-button-disappears)

[Navigation title disappears after use of custom back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455033/navigation-title-disappears-after-use-of-custom-back-button)

[navigation title on previous screen disappear when back button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506213/navigation-title-on-previous-screen-disappear-when-back-button-pressed)

[Missing Navigation's or Back Button's Title When Push ViewControllers in Succession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387260/missing-navigations-or-back-buttons-title-when-push-viewcontrollers-in-success)

Any ideas as to why this back button text disappears ?

Comment: does it help when you set navigationBar‘s tint color?

Comment: thanks for the idea @Mr.SwiftOak - however, still the same result

Answer (score 5):

So after a lot of trial and error, this is what seemed to have worked for me.

I needed to even specify what the attributes are of the `highlighted` state.

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
      NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.panoStoryYellow,
      NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Montserrat-SemiBold", size: 15)!
], for: .highlighted)
```

After this, the text never disappeared and everything worked as intended.

I am not marking this as the answer for now as perhaps someone has a better "right" way to do this.

In any case I am putting this answer here if anyone else might be facing a similar scenario.

Comment: I had a `setTitleTextAttributes` for `.normal` that caused the problem. I saw your answer and understood that I just needed to do the same but for `.highlighted`. Thanks!